# purge-wranglerを用いたeGPUの認識がうまくいかない

Tags: macos, gpu

Macbook pro mid2014に外付けGPU(egpu)をつけて外付けgpuから映像出力させるのがゴールです。

現在、以下のURLを参考にpurge-wrangler.shを用いてegpuを認識させようとしてますが、うまくいかず。
https://blog.goo.ne.jp/pinknoiz/e/7b347eadd8ac11e473b45e1b00911551

物理的なケーブルは以下のようになってます。
PC⇄TB2ケーブル⇄TB2,TB3変換ケーブル⇄egpu

OSバージョン
Big Sur
11.6.4

GPU
RADEON RX 6500XT

些細なことでも結構です。
情報をください。

うまくいかない点：
このMacについてのグラフィックスのところがIntel Iris 1536 MBのままになっている
参考URLにあるようなアイコンがメニューバーに追加されない

Comment: https://github.com/mayankk2308/purge-wrangler のドキュメントを見る限り、OS の対応バージョンが `10.13.4+` となっているようです。

Comment: cubick様　私もバージョンの違いかと思い、6.3.0も試したのですが、症状が変わりませんでした。

Comment: 同じドキュメントに System Integrity Protection と Secure Boot on T2 の条件が書かれていますが、これらがお手元の環境でどうなっているかは確認されましたでしょうか。参考になさっているリンク先の手順では前者も後者も特に変更していなさそうです。このため、まずは現状を知るのが良さそうです。

Comment: 内容を確認しました、ありがとうございます！現状確認してみます。